# Dynamically Change Page Content and Set Hash with AJAX/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, history

I am trying to create a webpage that will dynamically fill a div using AJAX. I have been able to simply update the div content with the following AJAX code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#projects-list a").click(function(e){ 
        e.preventDefault();
        var url = $(this).attr('href'); //get the link you want to load data from
        $.ajax({ 
            type: 'GET',
            url: url,
            success: function(data) { 
                $('#content').fadeOut(300, function() {
                    $('#content').html(data).delay(200).fadeIn(300);
                });
            } 
        }); 
    });
});
```

However, I also am hoping to find a way to update the page URL or change the hash. So for instance, when a user is given the link to */projects.html* they will be sent to a page of links, and then when a link is clicked the content is changed using AJAX and the url will change to */projects.html#first*. This way then a user navigates to */projects.html#first* they will see the content for the first project rather than the original list of projects to choose from.

Comment: Take a look at `history.js`. It wraps HTML URL rewriting in a way that works for HTML4 browsers too (by using hashtags on those). It provide change events you can use to do the dynamic navigation you want..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recomend to use a library to handle `URL` and `paths`

http://github.com/flatiron/director

http://balupton.github.com/history.js/demo

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use standard # then you can use via js, on a function call do : 
`window.location.hash = valueYouWantToSet`, some ID mostly,

and then you can check on page load if there is a # in there then call a particular function like :

```
handleHash: function () { if (!isNaN(parseInt(window.location.hash.replace('#', '')))){ this.showDetails(window.location.hash.replace('#', '')); }
```